# $f(x)\to 0\iff |x|\to 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, limits

There is a referenciable name for the class of positive functions continuous in $0$ that respect

$$f(x)\to 0\iff |x|\to 0$$

?

I should use this kind of function, and I am trying to get some reference on these. Thank you in advance.

Comment: zero at the vicinity of the origin

Comment: @Wuestenfux, I am sorry, but I did not understand your comment, I must have $\iff$. Thank you!

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no name for this class of functions. They can be easily described, though.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe This is what I think too, unfortunately I have not find any reference to studies for these functions. Thank you!

Comment: @Quiet_waters But what do you want to know about these functions ? I don't really see what is special with them.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I need to use this equivalence to prove some theorem, and will be good if I can say "if the function if XXXX (a name)", so the Theorem is proved... In fact, someone proves the theorem when $f$ is just a positive definite, but I am thinking there is a trouble with the presented proof, so I am seeking extra hypotehsis..

Comment: @Quiet_waters continuous functions that vanish at the origin?

Comment: @almosteverywhere yes, this can be an example! But there are other functions that respect this, am I right?

Comment: The fact that $f$ is continuous at $0$ is enough to say $|x| \to 0 \implies f(x) \to 0$. The other direction, $f(x) \to 0 \implies |x| \to 0$, has nothing at all to do with the behavior of $f$ at $0$. Instead it restricts the behavior of $f$ *everywhere else*. It says that *the only place $a$ where $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 0$ is at $a = 0$. At all other points $a. f$ must either diverge, or converge to a different value than $0$. This is far too specific a condition on $f$ to expect there to be much literature about such functions.

Comment: Thank you @PaulSinclair. I was thinking. Positive definite continuous radially unbounded functions...?

Comment: Actually my comment was a little off - there is no assumption that $f(0) = 0$, so continuity at $0$ is not sufficient to say that $|x| \to 0 \implies f(x) \to 0$. "Positive definite" is an appropriate description - but if you search for it, you will find it used pretty much exclusively for linear or differentiable functions, neither of which are assumed here. You also only posit continuity at $0$, not everywhere, so that too is more confining than your problem. and "radially unbounded" has no relationship I see to your conditions.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, I use positive definite as you can see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function#Alternative_definition (but ok, is really more confining). Moreover, radially unbounded+continuity will imply that the function cannot tends to $0$ any point beyond the origin... What do you think?

Comment: It is continuity (everywhere, not just at $0$) and that definition of positive definite that implies your condition. but not vice versa. If you also want to require $f(x) \not\to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$ (which is not clear from your post), then "radially unbounded" is overkill. All you need is for it not to converge to $0$, you don't have to have it diverge to $\infty$. There are plenty of bounded functions that fit your conditions.

Comment: @PaulSinclair yes you're right. Thank you